# Why my CUDA 10.1 is identified as CUDA 11.0 when trying to install Tensorflow in Windows 10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow 2.2 (or later) in Windows 10. According to the official Tensorflow instalation guide, Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later. I installed Anaconda with python 3.8 and then tried to install tensorflow using  `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow` but it displays 2 errors:

1. My Python version is not compatible (although the tensorflow page says the contrary).
2. My CUDA version is 11.0 (but I installed the 10.1 version as specified in the tensorflow installation guide).

In this picture I show [the message errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm7aG.png)

Additionally I tried using only `conda install tensorflow` but it displays the same messages as before.
I also tried doing the installation both inside and outside the enviroment I created named *sstensorflow* but it doesn't work.

Regarding the second error message, I used `nvcc --version` to check the installed version of the CUDA driver and it says it is version 10.1 as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elSnv.png).

So I don't know why my computer admits having CUDA 10.1 but when trying to install tensorflow it says I have CUDA 11.0 and also I don't know what is the error regarging my python version. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Had to go back to python 3.7. Other issue is that when it says
Your installed version is 11.0 I believe it is referring to your GPU card driver not the CUDA version. I had to find a driver version compatible with CUDA 10.1. I have an RTX 2070 GPU and the driver version I have is 26.21.14.3200. GO to the Nvidia site and search for a driver for your GPU card that is compatble with CUDA 10.1

Comment: I suspected going back to an earlier version of python would solve the problem but I  was trying to avoid going back to Python 3.7. I tried to use `conda install` because the online community suggested a `conda` install is better than a `pip` install for tensorflow, so I was trying to avoid using `pip`. But I realized that maybe conda is not yet up to date with the newest version of TensorFlow so I tried again with pip and it worked with no error messages. So the installation is fixed, thank you.

Comment: Conda works best to install tensorflow because it installs the CUDA toolkit and the proper version of cuDNN, Pip does NOT install these. You have do download them and follow a complex procedure to set it up properly including adding path variables Go back to 3.7 and get the right GPU driver and it will work..I believe Conda installs Tensorflow 2.1.0 which works fine